# Use of uninitialized value $intReason in array element PERL

Tags: perl

So I've been working on a report system using arrays but whenever I try to send a report it gives me this

`Use of uninitialized value $intReason in array element at Server/Systems/Messaging.pm line 26.`

I don't think it's really an error more like a warning cause everything works fine but it gives me that though.

here is the code

```
method handleSendReport($strData, $objClient){
    my @arrData = split('%', $strData);
    my $intPID = $arrData[5];
    my $intReason = $arrData[6];
    my $arrNickname = $arrData[7];
    my @reasons = ("Swearing", "Sexual Language", "Racial Words", "Personal Info", "Email Address", "Real Name", "Name Calling", "Bad Penguin Name");
    $objClient->botSay($reasons[$intReason]); #Line 26
}
```

Comment: Check your `$strData`. Does it contain all wanted fields? If it contains only 6 %-separated fields, then `$intReason` and `$arrNickname` will be uninitialized.

Comment: What do you mean by `%-`

Comment: You are splitting `$strData` by character `%`

Comment: Oh yes it does contain all of them

Comment: Can you give example of `$strData` ?

Answer (score 5):

The string in `$strData` contains fewer than six `%`, causing `$intReason` (and `$arrNickname`) to be undefined.

As such,

```
$objClient->botSay($reasons[$intReason]);
```

is equivalent to

```
$objClient->botSay($reasons[undef]);
```

which warns and is otherwise equivalent to

```
$objClient->botSay($reasons[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this line :
`my $intPID = $arrData[5];`
Try to print the value that you will assign to `$intPID` 
`use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $arrData[5];`
You will get an `use of uninitialized...` warning. This means that your array does not have an element defined on fifth index.